# How can I use combine variables to an exit variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem to convert 2 added variables to a local variable.
This is my original code.

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[4]=(aa+","+bb+","+cc+","+dd+","+ee+","+ff+","+gg+","+hh);
mycars[5]=(ii+","+jj+","+kk+","+ll+","+mm+","+nn+","+oo+","+pp);

var car4 = mycars[4].toString();
var car5 = mycars[5].toString();

var new_data4 = car4.split(",");
var new_data5 = car5.split(",");

var final_data = "new_data";

for(var i = 4; i < 6 ; i++){
  var c = final_data + i;

  alert(c[i]);// the result is d,a(the local array n,e,w,_,d,a,t,a)
}
```

I want this result is ee,nn

Comment: `c` is a string, not an array.  So `alert(c[i])` is basically alerting the fifth and sixth chars of the respective strings `new_data4...` and `new_data5...`.

Comment: sorry,but how can I convert string to exit variable?

Comment: You can't, unless the variables are global (in which case you can say `window[c][i]`).  But stop farting around with discrete variables for related data, and use an array or an object.  You'll be a better programmer for it, trust me.

Comment: (Bah.  Writing an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is not an array; it is a string.  So `alert(c[i])` is giving you back the fifth and sixth characters of the strings `new_data4` and `new_data5`, respectively.

If you want to use `c` as a variable name, *and* if these variables are global, then you can access your elements like `window[c][i]`.  But this *will not work* with local variables.  There is no standard way to access local variables by name.

Before you go making all your variables global, though, you don't need to access your variables by name at all.  If they were in an array, you could access them by number.

Watch this.

```
var new_data = [];
new_data[4] = [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh];
new_data[5] = [ii, jj, kk, ll, mm, nn, oo, pp];

for(var i = 4; i < 6 ; i++){
  alert(new_data[i][i]);
}
```

By the way, notice how all that stuff with the concatting values and stringifying the result, then splitting it again...is gone?  There's no need for it -- it's basically busywork.  You can create an array with the values already populated, and such an array should be your authoritative source of data.  If you need a string, then build it from the array -- not the other way around.

Aside from halving the amount of code you write, this also makes it possible to have commas in names without screwing everything up.  (Currently, if a name happens to have a comma, you throw off that name and everything after it.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var c = final_data + i;
```

Try to make it

```
  var c =  window[final_data + i];
```

Comment: I can't work.It seems have some problems

Comment: what problems it has??